# Google Places API - Nearby Search not filtering by type

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

The following URL Request is not filtering places by their types:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?type=establishment&location=-15.8374808,-48.0125697&radius=100&key=[YOUR_API_KEY_HERE]`

The query string `type=establishment` is not filtering property.

Note: insert your Google API Key in the end for search.

*Edit*: I believe only the first result is not in the filtered type. It's the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `establishment` type is not in the list of [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types) for place searches.

So your query is ignoring this type filter as if you were making the following typeless request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-15.8374808,-48.0125697&radius=100&key=KEY
```

You'll need to use a supported type such as e.g. `store`:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?type=store&location=-15.8374808,-48.0125697&radius=100&key=KEY
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Was looking at the list below in the docs, which has "establishment". Thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help :)