# Google Places Autocomplete not returning results for some types

Tags: angular, typescript, google-maps, ionic4, google-maps-autocomplete

I am using google places autocomplete to suggest schools for my users. The autocomplete is simply not working when I specify the type as school, or point_of_interest as another example. When I specify the type as establishment or geocode the autocomplete works fine.

I am using Ionic 4 and my autocomplete code looks like this:

## profile.page.ts

```
    getHighSchoolAutocomplete() {
          let input = this.highSchoolText;
          this.myHSAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input.nativeElement, {types: ['school']});
          google.maps.event.addListener(this.myHSAutocomplete, 'place_changed', () => {
            // retrieve the place object for your use
            let place = this.myHSAutocomplete.getPlace();
            console.log('initPlaces place getHighSchoolAutocomplete', place.formatted_address);
            this.addressHS = this.tmpParentInfo.get('myHighSchool').setValue(place.formatted_address);
          });
        }
      }
```

## profile.page.html

```
    <h5 class="ion-padding-start">High School:<br></h5>
    <input type="text" #highSchoolText formControlName="myHighSchool" class="highSchoolClass" id="googlePlaces1" class="ion-padding-start">
```

## index.html (the googlemaps api string)

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.26&key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

I have already tried the fixes here and no dice:
[Google Places Autocomplete not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20185606/google-places-autocomplete-not-showing-up)

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57826944/google-places-api-nearby-search-not-filtering-by-type

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that Autocomplete doesn't work because `school` is not a supported type for this service.

This is why it works when you specify `establishment` or `geocode` instead, as these *are* [supported types](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table3). You can only restrict results to `school` type (or any other type listed in [table 1](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types#table1)) in Place Search requests.

Hope this helps.